Fraction of times Alice redraw from N(0,1)
Alice and Bob are playing a game. Each of them draw a random number (one by one starting with Alice) from a standard normal distribution. They are not allowed to see the opponent's number, but are allowed to redraw the number on seeing their number.
The player with the higher final number wins the game. Given both players play the game optimally, what fraction of total redraws does Alice redraw?
The above question appeared in a probability test, and I wasn't able to approach it clearly. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
My current approach is to denote the random variable of the value drawn by Alice as $X$ and similarly $Y$ for Bob. Then Alice wants $X>E(Y)$ and Bob wants $Y>E(X)$.
So going with this approach it shall be something like Alice keeps redrawing until she gets $X>0$ (initial $E(Y)$). Then Bob keeps redrawing until he gets $Y>E(X|X>0)$, and then Alice again redraws until $X>E(Y|Y>E(X|X>0))$

The rules are not clear.  Can they redraw multiple times?  If so, why wouldn't they (theoretically) wait until they get a gigantic number?  But, that's what "Alice keeps drawing" would appear to suggest.

@lulu Yes, according to the question they can redraw multiple times, and that is what my intuition was. They drawing infinite time. But I think what's needed is the proportion of times Alice redraws in total number of redraws. Say in 100 draws how many time Alice redraws, then in 1000 and so on. Hopefully this number would converge.

Not following.  If $A$ can draw multiple times, then $A$ never stops drawing, so the percent is $100%$.  There is never a reason for $A$ to stop drawing in this game.

Assume for each redraw of Alice, Bob redraws 2 times. That is in first move Alice draws, then Bob, then Alice choose not to, then Bob, Alice choose not to, Bob does, then Alice does and so on. In this case Alice is redrawing 1/3 redraws

I saw this in the "I HRT math challenge" on mathdash today. The wording of this question is exactly the same there. I couldn't solve it initially but finally managed to get an accepted answer with help from a similar problem here. The only difference is that the distribution is Normal instead of uniform. Weirdly, it appears that the argument in 1 is totally independent of the distribution (as long as it is the same for both players), so the answer is same! Here is a sketch with all details:
First, to clarify, here is my interpretation of the question: The players are allowed to re-draw only once. I also assume that the players must be deterministic (though randomness can be easily accounted for in the arguments below). Thus, every strategy can be described by a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ denotes that we re-draw upon having received a real number $x$ in the first draw.
Next, I prove the following claim:
Claim: The optimal strategy $f_{\mathsf{opt}}$ is monotonous.

Proof: Let $p(x)$ denote the probability with which Alice wins if her final value is $x$ (when Bob follows the optimal strategy). $p(x)$ is clearly monotonous. Also let $\tilde{p}$ be the expected value of $p(x)$ when $x$ is drawn from the given distribution. It is easy to see that if Alice draws $x$ such that $p(x) < \tilde{p}$, then it is optimal to re-draw.

Thus, it suffices to find the smallest $z$ such that $f_{\mathsf{opt}}(z) = 1$.
Strategy: Suppose Alice drew $x$ in the first turn. Now she has to decide whether to re-draw or not. We will calculate the probability that she wins in both cases (say $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ resp) assuming that Bob follows the  optimal strategy. Note that although we haven't found $z$ yet, we can still derive expressions for $f_1, f_2$ in terms of $z$ (as we will show below). From our claim, it must hold that $f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \Leftrightarrow z \leq x$ (Cond 1.). Upon imposing (Cond 1). we can find $z$!
Evaluating $f_1, f_2$:
Let $g(x)$ denote the probability that a random drawn number according to the given distribution is less than $x$. The function $g(x)$ will be useful in our calculations.

Case 1 (Alice re-draws): We consider two further sub-cases.

Case 1(a): Bob re-draws. This happens w.p. $g(z)$. Subsequently the players have i.i.d. distributions and hence Alice wins w.p. 1/2. The total win probability for Alice in this case is $g(z)/2$.
Case 1(b): Bob does not re-draw. Let Bob's first draw be $Y$ and let Alice's re-draw be $X$. We require $(1-g(z)) \cdot \text{Pr}[X > Y \mid Y \geq z]$. Given $Y \geq Z$, $X > Y$ can be true only if $X \geq Z$, hence we can write $\text{Pr}[X > Y \mid Y \geq Z] = \text{Pr}[X > Y \mid (Y \geq Z \cap X \geq Z)] \cdot \text{Pr}[X \geq Z]$. The second term in the product is $1 - g(z)$. For the first term, observe that we are comparing two i.i.d. distributions and hence it evaluates to $1/2$. The final success probability in this case is $(1-g(z))^2 / 2$.



Summing over the two cases we get $f_1(x) = (1 - g(z) + g^2(z)) / 2$.

Case 2 (Alice does not re-draw): We consider similar sub-cases to Case 1.

Case 2(a): Bob re-draws. This happens w.p. $g(z)$. We succeed only if Bob's second draw is less than $x$. Hence Alice wins w.p. $g(z) g(x)$.
Case 2(b): Bob does not re-draw. Bob's first draw must (a) exceed $z$ and (b) be less than $x$. The corresponding probability is $g(z) - g(x)$.



The overall success probability in this case is $f_2(x) = g(z) g(x) + g(z) - g(x)$.
Finishing evaluation of $z$: From (Cond 1)., $f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ changes sign at $x = z$. Assuming $f_1, f_2$ are continuous $x = z$ is a root of $f_1-f_2$. It follows that $g^2(z) + g(z) - 1 = 0$ or $g(z) = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$, the golden ratio $\phi$.
The question asks for the fraction of time that Alice re-draws, which is exactly $g(z)$ so we don't have to bother computing $z$.

Thank you for your explanation. In case 1 a, are we assuming that Alice can't redraw again?
